# How to get a static IPv6 global unicast address for myself (an individual)?

Tags: ipv6

I want to get one static IPv6 Global Unicast for myself.  I want all the three parts **(the 48–64 bit prefix (i.e. address range) given to a customer by ISP; the 0–16 bit subnet ID chosen by the customer (or their router); and the 64-bit suffix (interface ID)** ) to be static and want to manually configure the address.

Answer (score 3):

> the 48–64 bit prefix (i.e. address range) given to a customer by ISP

Short answer: Call your ISP and ask.

All options, in no particular order:

1. With most residential ISPs, "fully static" is not an option. (They automate prefix assignment using DHCPv6 Prefix Delegation, so your router needs to run a DHCPv6 client capable of sending IA_PD requests.) Leasing a prefix works very much like leasing an IPv4 address – *the ISP* decides whether you'll be able to renew the same lease forever or whether it's forcefully changed every week.
2. Business ISPs and server hosting providers might use DHCPv6 PD as well (although it's much more likely that you'll get a static prefix), but it's also common for prefixes to be assigned statically. Sometimes that's automated, sometimes you need to open a support ticket and ask.
3. There still exist "tunnel brokers" offering IPv6 connectivity through a v6-in-v4 tunnel, and each tunnel usually comes with a static /48 prefix routed to you over the tunnel.
4. Combining the two above: if your local ISP does not offer an IPv6 prefix with the desired qualities, then rent a server from a hosting company which does – and then route it to your location through a VPN or plain tunnel.
5. ISPs themselves, and other large companies, obtain prefixes by becoming a member of a Regional Internet Registry (such as RIPE, ARIN, APNIC, etc.) and paying membership fees. By doing this, they become Local Internet Registries (LIRs) and get a /29–/32 prefix just to start with. They can use it themselves or assign sub-prefixes to customers such as you.

   (Being a LIR does cost a fair bit, and *only* gives you addressing, but actual network connectivity isn't part of the deal – you need to separately pay some ISP(s) for transit, physically connect to them somehow, and announce the prefix to them using BGP.)
6. Finally, you can find other people who make a business out of being a LIR and will sell you a /48-ish prefix and an ASN for a moderate fee (usually in the range of $200). Again, actual Internet connectivity not included.

Regarding the last two points: Whether individual can receive prefix or ASN assignments from a Registry seems to depend on region. As far as I know, under RIPE they can, but under ARIN they have to be an organization.

> the 0–16 bit subnet ID chosen by the customer (or their router) and the 64-bit suffix (interface ID)

Once you have a prefix (and of course – once it's routed to your network), *you* become the authority which controls addressing under that prefix. So just choose whatever values you like. You can start with subnet `0` and interface ID of `0:0:0:1`.

All operating systems will let you configure an IPv6 address statically, no special modes required.

---

<sub>Note that these field sizes are only a wide-spread convention, not a strict requirement. SLAAC requires the interface ID to be 64-bit (in most implementations), but IPv6 routing in general *does not*, and subnet routes aren't a distinct type from network routes. The same CIDR system as in IPv4 applies.</sub>

<sub>So if you assign addresses statically, then you're completely allowed to divide a prefix into, say, /80- or /96-sized subnets or any other unusual size. (Keeping in mind that just because you could, doesn't mean you should.)</sub>